# Logical and physical address with MMU on?

Tags: memory-address, mmu

I'm having some doubts about how kernel physical and logical addresses are handled by the MMU. I'll try to explain my question doing an example.
Let's doing the assumption that we are on an ARM architecture.

The system starts with the MMU off, so all the addresses which pass inside the CPU are physical. Before we enable the MMU we make a page table where we say that all our physical addresses are mapped at the virtual addresses `physical address + 0xC0000000`. After this we turn on the MMU. All of this is clear. But now questions start:

Since we are in a pipeline architecture let's say that the instruction after is a load from the address 0x8000. Now for my knowledge here we should have a page fault since the MMU doesn't find this address anywhere inside the page table, so it's invoked a page fault for handle the situation. But also if we've set the interrupt vector, inside it there's a branch to another physical address, so the MMU doesn't find this address and we fall unavoidably in an endless loop. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss that all used virtual addresses should be mapped even if in fact they match the same physical memory regions. Let's elaborate.

Say there is `startup` code (for primary initialisation and enabling MMU) and other `main` code (only to work with MMU enabled) with a following layout.

- startup - phys: 0x4000-0x7FFFF, virt: 0x4000-0x7FFFF
- main - phys: 0x8000-0xBFFF, virt: 0xC0008000-0xC000BFFF

Such a layout is linker job and your job is to feed it with a right script. CPU entry point in this example is supposed to be `0x4000`. That pretty much is a hardware specific address.

CPU starts with MMU disabled and 'PC=0x4000', and it continues till say `0x4800` when MMU is enabled.

So before enabling MMU there have to be maps for a `0x4000-0x7FFFF` (startup) and `0xC0008000-0xC000BFFF` (all other code).

Now MMU is enabled. PC has 0x4804 (assuming 32b CPU). `0x4804` is a **virtual address** now and it's mapped on `0x4804` **physical address**. CPU proceeds with `0x4804`, `0x4808`, `0x480C` etc.

At some point you should jump into a `main`. For **ARM** that would be something like

```
ldr r0, =0xC0008000
bx r0
```

Note, that **virtual address** of `main` entry is used. So after branching `PC=0xC0008000` which is resolved into `0x8000` in physical memory.

`0x4000-0x7FFFF` mapping could be removed after that.